# JS geocoder API

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to get latLon of searched location but the console log is saying that google is not defined can someone point me why its giving me that error. Read the doc on google but this code is similar to what they have.

```
var searchLocation = 'london';
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': searchLocation
            }, function(result, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var lat = result[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    var lon = result[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    callback();
                    console.log(lat + ', '+ lon);
                }
            });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4fm8715z/1/ (view console log)

Comment: Have you included the call to the google API in your HTML?

Comment: Yeah, put this one <script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?'></script> if you put this in the fiddle it says callback is not defined!